# VBA how to skip rows based on condition and stop when a specific number of conditions have been met

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm running a data file for a contest where there are two types of prizes.  The second prize is based on the first, but using VBA, I'm having difficulty skipping rows AND stopping at specific condition (count).

The output looks like this
[image: Imgur]

There are only 2 available for Prize2 and I want the VBA code to stop it at the 2nd successful Prize2

I've looked at Do Until Loops and For...Next options, but haven't gotten a successful code to stop the Prize 2 list without filling the entire column or getting an error

Below is what I'm using as code to get the table as it is now.  I previously had the code for the first two rows, but if a plant doesn't have Prize 1, then the 2nd Prize2 doesn't show.

```
'Portion using Prize 1 to determine Prize 2
Dim LastRowDest As Long
Sheets("ThisSheet").Select
LastRowDest = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("G2:G" & LastRowDest).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""Prize1"",""Prize2"","" "")"
```

This is how the output with two Prize2's available should look
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Within your `For...Next` or `For Each` loop, you need an `If [condition = True] Then Exit For`. This, as you might surmise, instructs the program to *exit* the loop when the condition is met. `Do Until [condition = True]` should also solve it, assuming you've implemented the loop propertly. Without a [mcve] example of the code you're using, it's not really possible to further assist. Also, please consider including example data as raw text rather than screenshots. The former are easier for others to copy/paste into a spreadsheet and therefore debug your problem.

Comment: Why not just modify the formula in column G? Adding a `COUNTIF` to count the number of previous instances of "Prize #2" should do the trick, if I understand the requirement correctly.

Comment: BigBen, I think I could make yours work, but I already got another solution in VBA.

Comment: David, I get what you're saying there, but I found an answer elsewhere.  But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that ended up working.  Hope I generic'd it up correctly

```
Dim P1Range As Range
Dim P1Cell As Range
Dim P2Range As Range
Dim Counter As Long
Set P1Range = Range("F7:F" & LastRowDest)
Set P2Range = Range("G7:G" & LastRowDest)
Counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(P2Range, "Prize2")
    For Each P1Cell In P1Range
            If P1Cell Like "*Prize1*" Then
                Counter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(P2Range, "Prize2")
                 'MsgBox Counter
                If Counter < 2 Then
                P1Cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "Prize2"                
                End If                 
            End If        
        Next P1Cell
```